# Index out of range error when attempting to go directly to the end of an array

Tags: ios, swift, indexoutofrangeexception

This is my array in the project in Xcode.

```
Var questions = ["q.1", "q.2", "q.3"]
```

I have added two buttons, i.e. forward button and backward button, to scroll through questions. Now when I first tap on the backward button as soon as I launch my project on simulator, so that it takes me to "q.3" directly, it gives me an error saying:

```
"Index out of range."
```

Bear in mind when I tap on the forward button initially it works fine and takes me "q.2" but it gives me an error when I tap on the backward button initially. Below is my code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel! //this is my question label 
questions = ["q.1", "q.2", "q.3"] //this is my array of questions

currentQuestionIndex = 0

@IBAction func backwardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

currentQuestionIndex -= 1
let noOfQuestions = questions.count
let previousQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex % noOfQuestions
question.text = questions[previousQuestionIndex]

@IBAction func forwardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

currentQuestionIndex += 1
let noOfQuestions =  questions.count
let nextQuestionIndex =  currentQuestionIndex % noOfQuestions
question.text =  questions[nextQuestionIndex]
```

Comment: error says what goes wrong. You trying to access element by index which is out of array range. You need to adjust index to array count f.e if index < 0 index = 0 or count -1  and if index > count index = count-1 or 0 as you wish

Comment: it is because of negative value of currentQuestionIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your forward and backward button to be disabled when you are on last and first question respectively. You can do the following:

Assuming your button's outlet named forwardButton & backwardButton initialize it as:

```
backwardButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

And make your IBAction for forward and backward buttons as:

```
@IBAction func backwardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    currentQuestionIndex -= 1
    if currentQuestionIndex == 0 {
        backwardButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO
    }
    forwardButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES
    let noOfQuestions = questions.count
    let previousQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex % noOfQuestions
    question.text = questions[previousQuestionIndex]
}

@IBAction func forwardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    currentQuestionIndex += 1
    if currentQuestionIndex >= questions.count - 1 {
        forwardButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO
    }
    backwardButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES
    let noOfQuestions =  questions.count
    let nextQuestionIndex =  currentQuestionIndex % noOfQuestions
    question.text =  questions[nextQuestionIndex] 
}
```

Or if you want it to behave as it is doing right now just do this in you IBAction for forward and backward buttons:

```
@IBAction func backwardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    currentQuestionIndex -= 1
    if currentQuestionIndex < 0 {
        currentQuestionIndex = questions.count - 1
    }
    question.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
}

@IBAction func forwardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    currentQuestionIndex += 1
    if currentQuestionIndex >= questions.count {
        currentQuestionIndex = 0
    }
    question.text =  questions[currentQuestionIndex] 
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to set the disallowed button's state to `.disabled` instead of turning off user interaction, because then there's a visual cue to the user that they can't tap it.

Comment: Thanks @NRitH. That would be better. So instead of 'userInteractionEnabled', you can use 'enabled' property.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This might Helpfull

```
@IBAction func backwardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

       currentQuestionIndex -= 1
       if currentQuestionIndex < 0
       {
          currentQuestionIndex = questions.count-1
       }
       question.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }

@IBAction func forwardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    currentQuestionIndex += 1
    if currentQuestionIndex >= questions.count
    {
       currentQuestionIndex = 0
    }
    question.text =  questions[currentQuestionIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check condition .

```
if currentQuestionIndex > 0{
    let noOfQuestions = questions.count
    let previousQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex % noOfQuestions
    question.text = questions[previousQuestionIndex]
  }
```